# Is there a formal general term for mathematical drawings?

Tags: terminology

I use the term “figure” and teach it to my students (high school). I like the terms “construct” and “construction” because all mathematics is made in our minds. A “figment” of our imaginations … But “construction” is reserved for straight edge + compass drawings. And for me it also conjures up images of building sites.

Personal preferences aside, **is there a formal (by convention) general term for bits of mathematical drawings?** For example, from simple angles to teach things like acute angle and three point notation, to complex geometric figures or graphs represented on a plane (inc. projections of 3D curves and surfaces).

Comment: Diagram/figure?

Comment: There is no standard term. Diagram, picture, graph, figure. illustration, etc.

Comment: Why do you say “construction” is reserved for straight edge + compass drawings?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist It’s a convention I was taught. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_and_straightedge_constructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any *general* term, but there is a *default* term, which is "figure". Indeed, this is the default [caption](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) chosen for $\LaTeX$ . That is, if you type

> \caption{This is a figure.}

then *by default* the caption appears as

> Figure 1: This is a figure.

Of course, there are options to change this behaviour, but this is a reasonable default choice, which seems to have the agreement of most mathematicians.

That being said, you can introduce your own term with a sentence like

> The picture [commutative diagram, graph, etc.] summarising these properties is represented in Figure 1.

Comment: If LaTeX uses “figure” as a general term, that’s a pretty significant usage. I hadn’t noticed that yet (I’m a light LaTeX user). I’ll mark this answer as correct, not for the LaTeX part but for writing an answer consistent with the other comments. I really wanted there to be a formal general word but I guess not all mathematical language is so rigorously formalised.